# Tensorflow allocates all GPU despite saying otherwise

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I want to run a script written on Python and using Tensorflow. SInce the server is shared with other colleagues, I would like to restrict my script to use at most 1/3 of the GPU memory the server has.

In order to accomplish that, I do the following :

`with tf.Graph().as_default():
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True, per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3)
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        log_device-placement=False,
        gpu_options=gpu_options)
    with tf.Session(conf=session_conf) as sess:
        # some stuff`

But when I check the GPU memory usage via `nvidia-smi` command it says that all of it is allocated. There are 2 GPU on the server and it seems that my script allocates fully both of them. What am I doing wrong ?

What I wrote above are not the first lines of code of the script. I first do some data processing. But if I put it in the very beginning, it does not change neither.

Answer (score 0):

One partial answer is to set an environment variable before calling the script called `$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0`. With this you can restrict the usage to the GPU-ID that you specify (GPU 0 in this example)

for more on that see [CUDA visible devices](http://www.acceleware.com/blog/cudavisibledevices-masking-gpus)